# Is there a limit to add images in a single android activity?

Tags: android, gridview

Well I have an activity where I use a grid view to show images statically. The thing is that when I add more than 3 images i.e. when i add the 4th image and run the activity the "app unexpectedly stops" and following error comes up.

Android monitor

```
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.roadraz.vcademy1, PID: 30272
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35093260 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 11MB until OOM
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:811)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:418)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.roadraz.vcademy1.GridImageAdapter.getView(GridImageAdapter.java:41)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1439)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:366)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:307)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:442)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1282)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
04-16 02:03:26.517 30272-30272/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.view.C
```

Comment: size of your image is way high... try to reduce it ad try again.. i'm sure it will work.

Comment: no there is no limit to add images in  activity.Your are getting the out of memory exception because your image size is too large,reduce it and try again.

Comment: ohhh...ok...thank you...will try and revert back!!

Comment: It is working...but i want to ask...is the memory allocation divided with respect to each cell of the gridview?

Comment: No. It's app-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the classic OOM problem. It has nothing to do with android activity.
For short you can do following the steps as [the android training guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

And I recommend you to see this [discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) for more detail. :)